# Wrong encoding size with struct.pack "Hq"

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, pack

I'm trying to encode a short (2 bytes) and a long long (8 bytes) into a bytes array with struct.pack, and the output has a size of 16 instead of 10:

```
import struct
print(len(struct.pack('Hq',1,2))) #show 16 and not 10
```

NB: `len(struct.pack('H',1))` properly returns 2, and `len(struct.pack('q',2))` properly returns 8

Is this a python bug ? I'm using Python 3.9.5

Comment: What makes you think it should be 10?

Comment: You're seeing *alignment* in action here - you need to choose a `struct` format (first character of the string) that avoids alignment, if you don't want it.  Note that `struct` without an explicit format is platform-dependent, anyway.

Comment: @jasonharper calcsize('qH') is the expected 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of padding, carried out for greater interoperability with C code/libraries (see the note at the top of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).).

If you wish to disable the padding, do

```py
import struct
print(len(struct.pack('=Hq',1,2)))  # now shows 10
```

You can read about the `=` and other special format characters in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `calcsize` function from `struct` to see the size based on the format you're using.

For `Hq`

```
from struct import calcsize

calcsize('Hq')
```

Per the docs: The ordering of format characters may have an impact on size since the padding needed to satisfy alignment requirements is different.

If you switch the order, you'll get your expected 10:

```
from struct import calcsize

calcsize('qH')
```

Comment: calcsize('Hq') also return 16, but that doesn't make any sense to me, it's still not 2+8=10...

Comment: When I look at the details of the byte encoding, it looks like it's encoding the short as requested with 2 bytes, and then pads with 6 zeros, and then encode the long long as requested with 8 bytes.

Comment: @RobinLobel if you switch the order you get your 10. Check the docs for more info about how the order can impact padding. https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Answer (score 0):

It's due to alignment. If you don't specify any flag at the beginning of your format string, @ will be used, which is using a "native alignment":
https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment

Starting the format string with any other flag (=, <, > or !) will remove this alignment.

`calcsize('=Hq')` will return 10 as expected.